# Move dropped files to folder X, otherwise just open X with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I would like to create an Applescript that mimics the behavior of an alias to a specific folder X.  If files are dragged to it, they should be moved to folder X, but if the Applescript is just double-clicked, folder X should be opened.

I am an Applescript novice, but adapting things I've found on the web, I have constructed working pieces: one that moves dragged files to X and one that opens X.  I do not know enough to combine them with "if...else" logic, so that if nothing is dragged, the folder is opened; but if things are dragged, they are moved to X but X is not opened.

```
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems
        set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems
        tell application "Finder"
            set folderMyFolder to folder "/Users/myname/myfolder"  
            move theCurrentDroppedItem to folderMyFolder
        end tell
    end repeat
end open

tell application "Finder" to open "Macintosh HD:Users:myname:myfolder"
```

Answer (score 0):

When your script contains an `open` handler, it will be passed items dropped onto the application, while the `run` handler is the one called when the application is double-clicked.  You don't need to do any comparisons, just place the statements to be performed in the appropriate handler, for example:

```
property targetFolder : ((path to home folder) as text) & "path:to:myfolder"

on run
    tell application "Finder" to open folder targetFolder
end run

on open droppedItems
    repeat with anItem in droppedItems
        tell application "Finder" to move anItem to folder targetFolder
    end repeat
end open
```

Note that the Finder doesn't know about POSIX paths, so to use them you will need to coerce the paths to something the Finder can handle, or use something that does know POSIX paths, such as System Events.

Comment: Can't you remove the repeat loop and simply `tell app id "com.apple.Finder" to move the droppedItems to the targetFolder` ?

Comment: @CJK Yes you can, I just wanted to make it obvious that `droppedItems` was a list.

Comment: Ok, understood.